# cmake error( add_executable) I am not getting what eerror it is. Also i get CXX_STANDARD is set to invalid value '17'

Tags: c++, cmake, cmake-language

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

project(FireliteApp C CXX)
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
string(LENGTH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/" SOURCE_PATH_SIZE)
add_definitions("-DSOURCE_PATH_SIZE=${SOURCE_PATH_SIZE}")
find_package(Threads)

add_executable(FireliteApp src/dependency/Serial.cpp src/dependency/LinuxTimer.cpp src/dependency/data_type.cpp src/dependency/TASDP_COMM.cpp 
                            src/dependency/DriverAppConfig.cpp src/dependency/JSONData.cpp 
                            src/dependency/boot_data.cpp src/dependency/config_rx.cpp src/dependency/queue.c
                            src/sbus/core/SBusPkt.cpp src/sbus/core/sendsbus.cpp 
                            src/sbus/expander/expander_sbus.c src/main.cpp
               )

include_directories(include/ include/sbus/Core include/sbus/Expander include/dependency "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}")
target_include_directories(FireliteApp PUBLIC  include)
target_include_directories(FireliteApp PUBLIC  ../inc)

set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -lrt -lm -g -pipe -Wall -lpthread ")

target_link_libraries(FireliteApp rt pthread )

set_property(TARGET FireliteApp PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 17)
```

Please help me out. 
I'm new to CMake

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post the **error messages** you are seeing in your question post as text, not only in the title.

Answer (score 1):

Error message

> CXX_STANDARD is set to invalid value '17'

means that you attempt to set `CXX_STANDARD` property (or `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD` variable) to the value, which is **not supported** in the given CMake **version**.

List of possible values for the property can be found in the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/prop_tgt/CXX_STANDARD.html) for the property. Such way it could be found that support for `CXX_STANDARD` equal 17 has been added only in CMake version 3.8.

---

Since the project uses a feature available since CMake 3.8, it has a little sense to specify lesser version in `cmake_minimum_required`. With proper

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
```

attempt to build the project with older CMake will immediately give an appropriate error.

Comment: what about add_executable error which i see.. in this Cmake

Comment: Such a way CMake points to the line which creates an executable with invalid property.

Comment: And what about following the [comment to your question post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61100174/cmake-error-add-executable-i-am-not-getting-what-eerror-it-is-also-i-get-cxx/61100656?noredirect=1#comment108093973_61100174) and adding the **exact error message** into the question's body? Such a way the error message could be correctly formatted and easily seen by other readers. Not to say that fix would help you with downvotes...